# Salesforce for Outlook Configuration-Contacts - Event - Task syncing disabled

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook

Salesforce for Outlook Configuration-Contacts - Event - Task syncing disabled

I am an administrator still cannot edit it.

Here is the screenshot[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Setup > Desktop Administration > Outlook Configurations

Here is where you setup your different Salesforce for Outlook Configurations for your users/profiles. Most likely cause of your problem is that the System Administrator profile (or maybe just your User) is a member of a configuration which doesn't allow for individual users to decide what syncs and what doesn't sync.

Edit your Outlook Configuration(s) and look under the Contacts, Events, and Tasks sync options and you will see a bunch of options that you can choose to allow your users to modify their individual sync settings, or if you prefer, to lock them up so that users can't change what syncs and what doesn't.

In your case, you want to at least check the box for "**Allow Users to Modify: Whether an object is synced**" IF you want them to be able to modify those settings on their own.

IF however you are trying to just enable the sync of all of those objects globally for all users and NOT let them change it, you can leave "**Whether an object is synced**" unchecked and instead just setup the Sync Direction/Conflict behavior globally.

More info on Outlook Configurations:

https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=outlookcrm_config_create.htm&siteLang=en_US

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

this happened to me recently.  To fix it, in Setup - Email - Outlook Configurations, click on the name of the your Outlook Configuration (not the edit button). Scroll down to the bottom where it says data sets and hit edit. Set your filters and save them.  This should enable syncing. [image: data sets]

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well, but the root of the issue was that I had not yet added the user to the list of "Assigned Users and Profiles". Its a silly mistake, but I had never set up a user for this before and didn't know I had to add them. I fixed this via the following steps:

- Go to Setup --> Desktop Administration --> Outlook Configurations
- Click edit at the top of the page
- Add the new User to the list of “Assign Users and Profiles” and click Save

The user closed and re-opened outlook, and the syncing process began. One warning: When the initial syncing began, Outlook threw several errors messages and crashed once. After a few minutes the errors stopped and the syncing was successful.

(Adding Profiles instead of Users seems like best practice to me, but our organization hasn't done this yet so the Users have to be added manually for now)